# video bad resolution it stuck in some frames

Tags: after-effects, video-recording, export, rendering, screenshot

I try to design video that include phone screen recording.
the phone recording is good resolution out after effects
when i add it to after effects it's stuck in some frames and it seems bad resolution!
any advise please?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Being a .mov shouldn't cause that issue on its own.  Video files have wrappers and codecs. The ".mov" file name is just the wrapper. The codec is the way the file is encoded inside the wrapper, which you can see by opening the file in something like Quicktime Player and clicking on Window --> Show Movie Inspector.

Most files on phones are stored in lossy formats.  When you convert these again to another lossy format like mp4 you will lose some more quality.

You might get a sharper looking result by converting your original file to a lossless format like ProRes or an Animation codec.  You can do this using Adobe Media Encoder.

Answer (score -1):

Finally I find out the problem!
It's happen because the video format was .mov
Just convert it to mp4 by online tool then everything was ok!